# Template parameter deduction for constructors from initializer list

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

At the [Kona](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/11/kona-standards-meeting-trip-report) meeting, template parameter deduction for constructors ([P0091R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0091r0.html)) has been approved. It simplifies some variable definitions:

```
std::pair   p  {1,2};     // o.k., constructor pair<int,int>(1,2)
std::vector v1 (10, 0);   // o.k., 10 zeroes, constructor vector<int>(size_t n, T initvalue)
std::vector v2 {10, 0};   // o.k., 2 values: 10, 0, apparently initializer list?
std::vector v3 = {10, 0}; // o.k., same as v2?
```

However, the following lines do not compile in gcc 7 HEAD 201611 version ([live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fcMOMj4mAthWAumU)):

```
std::vector v4 = {3};     // error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector(int)'
std::vector v5 {1, 2, 3}; // error: 'int' is not a class
std::set    s  {1, 2, 3}; // error: no matching function for call to 'std::set(int,int,int)'
```

Are these just "a bridge too far", since they involve initializer lists?
Are they covered by template type parameter deduction? 
Will they be allowed, when compilers conform to C++1z?

Comment: I think your `same as v3?` is a typo.

Comment: @John Zwinck: Yes, thanks, corrected.

Comment: The original proposal simply didn't have the right wording. We have some [massive standardese fixes](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/954e86feae0c5cbb80c2c506fd5e3db4993bf60a) incoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an extra pair of curly braces to make your code work correctly:

```
std::vector v4 = {{1, 5}}; 
std::vector v5 {{1, 2, 3}};  
std::set    s  {{1, 2, 3}};
```

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with aggregate initialization? There is no aggregate anywhere.

Comment: @T.C. I thought that the double curly braces were required to avoid the same issues that occurred when constructing `std::array`, but it doesn't really make sense for vector. What's the actual reason for requiring double curly braces?

Comment: They didn't get the wording right :/ We have a fix incoming for the standardese, and then the implementations will presumably be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to call the `foo::foo(const initializer_list &)` constructor, you need to tell the compiler that there's **exactly** one argument, so you need an extra pair of parentheses or braces:

```
std::vector v5 ({1, 2, 3});
std::set    s  ({1, 2, 3});
               ^         ^
```

In this way, the compiler knows that you're calling a function with only one argument as `const initializer_list &`, instead of a function with three `int`s.